# Как в C# конвертировать изображение произвольного формата в матрицу?

Tags: c#, изображения

**Можно ли создать `Int24` (24-битовый тип) в C#?**

Основная задача:

1. Залить каждую отдельную белую область на бинарном изображении уникальным цветом `color` формата `Format24bppRgb`    (`color++` для каждой очередной области).
2. Получить полный список таких объектов, состоящих из конечного набора пикселей.

Comment: А что вам мешает использовать 24 бита из 32 и не делать отдельный тип?

Comment: Ну, создать-то можно, заведите структуру из трёх `byte`. Но зачем? Я бы просто использовал массив байт, соответствующий заполнению памяти, и написал процедуры, которые читают/пишут значение по индексу. (Кстати, не забудьте про stride.)

Comment: Мне хотелось бы редактировать Bitmap одним присваиванием в формате 24bppRgb, а не отдельными byte-компонентами RGB, которые в данной задаче смысловой нагрузки не несут.

Comment: @DukeSpontaneous: Ну, наверное имеет смысл. Но если вы заведёте массив таких `Int24`, вы собираетесь его копировать в память картинки побайтно? (Потому что из-за выравнивания за-blit-ить вы его скорее всего не сможете.) Поверьте моему опыту, будет медленно. (Впрочем, попробуйте.)

Comment: @VladD: Нет, сейчас я банально раскладываю изображение в `uint` матрицу через `Buffer.BlockCopy`, чтобы работать с ним в 2D координатах. Но чисто теоретически мне интересно, как его, например, можно разложить в матрицу по 24 бита из `BitmapData.Scan0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы подошли к задаче не с той стороны. Вы, видимо, пытаетесь сделать 24х-битный тип данных чтобы расположить его в массиве, который повторит по структуре картинку. Но в C# так сделать затруднительно.

Вместо этого, можно сделать отдельный класс с индексатором, который будет выглядеть снаружи как массив - а внутри будет сам правильно раскладывать цвета пикселей по байтам:

```
public class BitmapAccessor {
  private byte[] scan0; // Или любое другое хранилище
  private int stride; // (3 * width + 3) / 4 * 4. Ну или можно взять это число из BitmapData.Stride

  // ...

  public Color this[int x, int y] {
    get {
      var index = 3 * x + stride * y;
      return Color.FromArgb(scan0[index], scan0[index+1], scan0[index+2]); // точный формат не помню, возможно аргументы надо поменять местами
    }
    set {
      var index = 3 * x + stride * y;
      scan0[index] = value.R;
      scan0[index+1] = value.G;
      scan0[index+2] = value.B;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Не обязательно строить велосипед. Возьмите готовый класс `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, он позволяет работать с пикселями как вам нравится, включая выбор глубины от 4 до 48 бит, указанный вами формат, и еще несколько специфических форматов. Больше подробностей в [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx).

Заливку, правда, придется реализовывать самостоятельно, готовой нет. Но можно воспользоваться векторными возможностями, если скормить `Bitmap` в конструктор `Graphics`.

С цветом, можно работать с помощью класса `System.Drawing.Color` и методов `FromArgb()` и `ToArgb`, которые дают возможность получить и задать цвет обычным `int`. Подробности в документации [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.color(v=vs.110).aspx), [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.color.toargb(v=vs.110).aspx) и [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2zys7833(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Я пока решил банально работать в формате Format32bppRgb.
Но мне было интересно, не предусмотрено ли каких-нибудь удобных средств для работы с 24-битным форматом, который весьма популярен: ведь при отсутствии типов соответствующего размера намного сложнее даже банально преобразовать считанное изображение в матрицу. Или вы предлагаете читать по пикселю через класс?

Comment: @DukeSpontaneous а как вы планируете делать заливку не обращаясь к отдельным пикселям? может я просто чего не знаю, но это вроде как единственный вариант для растра.

Comment: @ rdorn: да, я делаю это обращаясь к отдельным пикселям, но не множественно вызывая метод `GetPixel()` класса `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, а работая с  копией, разложенной в `uint`'овую матрицу.

Comment: @DukeSpontaneous ну если очень нужна высокая производительность, то, насколько я понимаю, в `unsafe` блоке можно просто получить указатель на матрицу изображения и работать с ней напрямую. Хотя я такого не делал еще.

Comment: @DukeSpontaneous от использования методов производительность сильно проседает? Мне кажется, если мудрить с созданием отдельной структуры для 24bpp сильно лучше не станет, все равно накладные расходы будут, это уже мерять надо

Comment: @ rdorn: в том-то и дело, что там не матрица, а линейный массив, заполненный пикселями в выбранном формате.
А на счёт производительности я не сравнивал, а просто предположил, конечно. Тут я сам себе усложнил задачу скорее просто в образовательных целях.

Comment: @DukeSpontaneous https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.scan0(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1 тут как раз ваш случай похоже. И даже без `unsafe`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37379/discussion-between-rdorn-and-dukespontaneous).

Answer (score 1):

1. Использовать только 24 бита из 32-х битного числа.
2. Создать отдельную структуру с тремя байтами или отдельный класс с массивом из 3 байт.

Comment: Лучше структуру, чтобы соответствовало Int32 по поведению.

Comment: @VladD Согласен, можно и структуру.

Comment: @VladD Вообще, по-моему этот вопрос поднимается с завидной периодичностью. И наверняка ответ на  него не сложно было бы найти.

Comment: Ну, тогда наверное стоило закрыть как дубликат?